# Topology - A continuous map from the circle that can be extended to a continuous map from the disc is null

Tags: general-topology

a question from my h.w.

> Let $h:S^1 \rightarrow X$ be continuous map, and suppose it can be extended continuously to the Disc meaning there exists a continuous map $k:D^2 \rightarrow X$ such that $k|_{S^1}=h$.
>
> Show explicitly that $h$ is nulhomotopic *without* using the induced homomorphism $h_*$ between the fundamental groups.

Munkres deals with this topic through the use of group homomorphisms. I have a feeling this is particularly simple and that I'm expected to construct some straight forward homotopy using $k$. I admit that I don't fully understand the significance of the fact that a map can be continuously extended as in this problem - what does this imply and how can I use a map defined on the disc to construct a homotopy on the circle?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a straightforward homotopy using $k$ is the thing. Unfortunately, I have no idea for a hint that wouldn't give it all away.

Comment: What is a cylinder mod one of its boundary circles?

Comment: Alternative hint: polar coordinates.

Comment: I'll take mlk's hint. I want to treat the disc with polar coordinates - it is comprised of all points $re^{i\varphi}$ for $0\leq r\leq1$. I define the homotopy to be $k(r,\varphi)$ and since $k(0)=0$ and $k(1,\varphi)=h$ this is the desired homotopy. Correct?

Comment: I realize I had a basic misunderstanding regarding the definition of a homotopy which is why I didn't understand this approach immediately. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have $k(0) = 0$. But whatever it is, it is some constant.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was just a bit sloppy there.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the disc with polar coordinates - it is comprised of all points $re^{i\varphi}$ for $0 \leq r \leq 1$. Define the homotopy to be $k(r,\varphi)$ and since $k(0,\varphi)=k(0)$ is some constant, and $k(1,\varphi)=h$ this is the desired homotopy.